# How to convert RGB code to 8 simple intervals (possible ?)

Tags: algorithm, colors, rgb, pseudocode

I'm working on my Final Bachelor Project in Computer Science and for now I'm in a dead end.
Here is what I got stuck on:

I'm trying to classify any color (rgb code) in any of 8 (eight) simple colors.
In short terms I need to find 8 intervals where any colour can be placed and be considered a basic color (red, blue, green, black, yellow, purple, grey, brown ).

*example:* 
  (18,218,23)  to be classified as "green"
          
(81,,214,85) also "green" 
          
  but 
           (15,52,16) needs to be "black"
           (110,117,110) needs to be "grey"

So there are 256 x 256 x 256 possible colors and I need to divide them in 8 (intervals) basic colors.

I'm waiting for some suggestions.

Cheers !

---

To be clear (as I've seen in comments) I'm looking for a particular set of 8 colors (red, black, green, brown, blue, purple, grey, yellow). Sorry for the orange above !

Comment: Can't you just specify intervals in an if-else block?

Comment: nope, that means 16777216 if/else blocks ... so ... i don't have so much time to write all that

Comment: Um... no it doesn't. You can specify ranges in your if-else blocks... For example, black could mean something like <60, <60, <60, etc.

Comment: What about calculating the distance of the colour that is to be classified to each of the eight "primary" colours? If you do this, you should keep in mind that short distances in the RGB space do not necessarily correspond to human perception. For that, you should convert to LUV or a similar space.

Comment: How you can do this depends on exactly which colours you want to classify as what. Then again, once you determine that, you pretty much already have your algorithm right there.

Comment: Whichever way you end up choosing will for some colours be subjectively wrong to some people anyway. People don't really agree on how to label colours that are "in between" proper colours.

Comment: Green is not a basic color according to that you wrote.

Comment: guys @ysap 's  comment is the most efficient solution !

Comment: http://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/

Comment: You list 8 colors in the question, but then your sample uses a color not in the list (green).  Are the colors specific, or just a general concept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your example, I'd start with determining whether all components are approximately the same, or does on stand out. If they are about the same, then decide if the values are small enough to be black or not, then it's grey. If one value is different from the other two, then it is easy to check which is different and pick one of six possible colors accordingly.

Alternatively, set each component to either 0 or 1 according to a threshold, then you have 8 combinations to map to 8 colors.

```
threshold = 100:
(18,218,23)   -> (0, 1, 0) - to be classified as "green"
(81,214,85)   -> (0, 1, 0) - also "green"
(15,52,16)    -> (0, 0, 0) - to be "black"
(110,117,110) -> (1, 1, 1) - to be "grey"
```

Comment: This a great idea ! Thank you so much ! It's simple and light!weight

Comment: @ysap - don;t do this in RGB, especially if the data is coming from a camera or any 'real' source it will never work properly and be a rela pain - honestly!

Comment: This gives you eight colors, but they are _different_ colors than the OP specified.  (red, blue, orange, black, yellow, purple, grey, brown)

Comment: @MooingDuck Can you be more specific ?

Comment: @MooingDuck, Martin Beckett - the OP did not specify an application (like camera). The colormap, and the threshold (or thresholds, as there can be different ones for each channel) can be set to whatever values he wants to give more meaningful or accurate colors. Note that the "white" color is also missing from the table in the description, and so is the green.

Comment: @VladU: You asked for "red, blue, orange, black, yellow, purple, grey, brown", but ysap's algorithm (though fast and simple) gives "black, blue, green, seagreen, red, purple, yellow/orange, white/grey"

Comment: @ysap: To adjust your algorithm to give the colors asked for (interesting note about green, I don't know what to make of that), it would make it _vastly_ different.

Comment: @MooingDuck I don't need white.

Comment: @MooingDuck - I agree with you on that, but again, note that the example vectors are different from the colors in the table (missing green), so my assumption is that this is not really a photographic algorithm exercise but rather an introductory exercise in programming. As which, the principle here is more important. again - if the colors in the list are actually required, then my method is not the appropriate one (w/o colorspace conversion).

Comment: @ysap The data is coming from a camera. First I take a picture then I see wich is "the main" color in that photo. So i'll guess that will be ok.

Comment: @VladU: if the _specific colors_ aren't important, then I would definitely go with this answer.  (Also please add that information to the question for future visitors)

Comment: @MooingDuck Sorry for confusion. I'm looking for 8 specific colors.

Comment: @VladU: if you want those 8 specific answers, then sadly, this answer is not a very good approach.

Comment: @MooingDuck, VladU: nor is the question clear. MVM, I see the question is corrected now.

Comment: @MooingDuck Why not ? it seems to me that this is a good aproach. please tell me what is missing ? or why this won't work

Comment: @VladU: As I already said, this algorithm will group colors into the categories of  "black, blue, green, seagreen, red, purple, yellow/orange, white/grey".  You can shift the lines slightly, but they will still be centered on those categories.

Answer (score 8):

Don't do this in RGB, convert to a more convenient color space [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) is probably easiest - then the 8 "colors" are simply 8 intervals along the Hue axis.

Comment: Thanks Martin. This seems pretty good solution. I'll do more research about HSV color space.

Comment: the wikipedia article includes enough info to do this (done it many times myself!)

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to do the distance from a defined points that you have labeled as a specific color. This is not a full proof solution, however it is an easy solution, and should work decently.

Long answer: Color spaces are annoying and don't translate well to labels.

Comment: thanks ! i think that will work, anyway i'm looking for a simpler algorithm

Comment: Thats as simple as you're going to get it. You have to hand pick 8 points and label the colors, but thats as simple as it'll get.

Answer (score 1):

RGB is horrible for this kind of thing, so your first step should be converting the color to a [Lab color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color). You can find many open implementations of this conversion online. Once you have your Lab color, everything becomes very simple. The three values become coordinates in three dimensions which you can easily section according to color - check out the images in the wikipedia link.

Comment: I think that HSV may be better for this problem.

Comment: What makes you think that? HSV is a step in the right direction, but is not a very good representation of the human color perception, which is what we are after.

Comment: @qwertyboy - but if you are dividing RGB values into only 8 colors then details of human perception probably aren't top of the list! HSV maps simple 'color' into a single angle

Comment: @martin - I disagree. It's not **detailed** perception, but it's still perception. We want everything that a person calls "blue" to be close together, and that's best achieved (to my knowledge) with Lab colors. I agree, however, that the improvement may be small, and HSV is far cheaper to compute.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know too much about Color scheme but calculating Euclidean distance would be a good solution.

Comment: No - full Red (255,0,0) full Blue(0,0,255) and Grey(140,140,140) are all the same Euclidean distance from black

Comment: @MartinBeckett: I don't immediately see the relevance of that.  My first response to this question would be exactly this.  Sure, a tiny number of colors might be equidistant from one or more of the "basic colors", in which case one can be arbitrarily selected.